# How to check a string has value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am running a MySQL query in MySQL-workbench. The query is simplified as:

```
SELECT name1, name2, alg1, alg2 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE CONCAT('www.',name1) = name2
AND ((alg1 != NULL) AND (alg2 != NULL));
```

I get 0 results. Although I am sure that there are records that satisfies the criteria of having all conditions met.

When I remove the second conditions, so my query becomes:

```
SELECT name1, name2, alg1, alg2 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE CONCAT('www.',name1) = name2;
```

I get many records which has `alg1` and `alg2` contain strings and are not `NULL`. `alga1` and `alg2` are fields of type `VARCHAR(500)`. They contain strings which can contains spaces, and may contain nothing. Please note that I do not enter the string `null` nor `NULL` manually. Just an empty field, which as far as I understand will contain `NULL` in the value `NULL` or `null`.

How can I make a condition that states that `alg1` and `alg2` should have a value in the field and are not empty fields?

Comment: You did read how to compare nullable values, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare a value to `NULL`. Instead you should use the statement `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT name1, name2, alg1, alg2 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE CONCAT('www.',name1) = name2
AND ((alg1 IS NOT NULL) AND (alg2 IS NOT NULL));
```

You can find more detailed information about this in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html).